# Windows Store Apps ImageMap control?

Tags: asp.net, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is there any Windows Store apps that's similar to ASP.NET [ImageMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagemap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control

I want to have an image with defined clickable regions, when a region is clicked the event gets fired.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
       Image image = new Image();
       image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/images.png"));
               image.Width = 50;
               image.Height = 50;
              image.Tapped += new TappedEventHandler(pushpin_tapped); 
              MapLayer.SetPosition(image, new Location(latitude, longitude));

               layer.Children.Add(image);
    private void pushpin_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //you can handle your event here
    }
```

for multiple events or ui-elements you can define a user control.Hope this can help

Comment: thanks,for the helpful answer, but I wanted to have clickable areas on an Image (not geographical maps). something similar to SVG files